# how to remove similar coordinates from two dataframes

Tags: r, duplicates

I have two sets of data which contain coordinates. I want to remove the similar coordinate from "DATA.xlsx".

you can download the data from
[DATA](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1lEsSYUicM3blQJNbsDADQfFZsnG-gwjj?usp=sharing)

I used this code to do that:

```
b1 = read_excel('DATA.xlsx')
d1 = read_excel('data2.xlsx')
b1 = b1[!(b1$y %in% d1$y),]
```

I does the job but the problem is since it only uses one variable to do so, sometimes it gives me different results because sometimes I have two y coordinates and removes the wrong row. I tried with x coordinates too. It has the same problem. I want to modify the code in a way to use both x coordinate and y coordinate then match the data from the two files and remove them.

Comment: Saber, this is an interesting problem. Obviously, coordinates define a location in space (or plane). One could argue, 2 locations are similar, if the distance between them is not bigger than a threshold. However, if Point A is similar to Point B, and Point B similar to Point C, but C not to A, you need to work out whether you keep Point B only (2 similarities) or keep Point A and Point C (which are distinct). TO get you going you can calculate the distance between the points in `data2` and `DATA` ... hope below helps you get going.

Answer (score 0):

I have not had the time to download your data. Thus, the following is a simplification of your datasets.

```
X1 = c(1,2,4,5,1,3,1)
Y1 = c(3,5,6,3,1,5,1)
DATA= data.frame(X1,Y1)

X2 = c(2,3,4)
Y2 = c(3,4,2)
data2= data.frame(X2,Y2)
```

Let's label the points to have a better human readable data frame

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data2 <- data2 %>% mutate(POINT = LETTERS[1:nrow(data2)])   # add letters to data2
DATA <- DATA %>% mutate(CAND = paste0("C",1:nrow(DATA)))    # candidate for similarity

# combine both datasets and calculate "euclidean distance" between point and candidate
df <- tidyr::expand_grid(data2,DATA) %>% 
  mutate(DIST = sqrt((X2-X1)^2 + (Y2-Y1)^2))
```

This gives us

```
      X2    Y2 POINT    X1    Y1 CAND   DIST
   <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
 1     2     3 A         1     3 C1     1   
 2     2     3 A         2     5 C2     2   
 3     2     3 A         4     6 C3     3.61
 4     2     3 A         5     3 C4     3   
 5     2     3 A         1     1 C5     2.24
 6     2     3 A         3     5 C6     2.24
 7     2     3 A         1     1 C7     2.24
 8     3     4 B         1     3 C1     2.24
 9     3     4 B         2     5 C2     1.41
10     3     4 B         4     6 C3     2.24
```

You can now filter according to the distance threshold and check how close the "candidates" in DATA are vs data2.

You can now filter on the (distance)threshold criterion:

```
threshold <- 1.5   # let's pick a threshold 

similar <- df %>% 
   filter(DIST < threshold)
```

This gives you then a list of points Px in data2 that could "replace" similar points in DATA. And you can decide which candidates to eliminate.

There is now different ways to go on. But for this you have to specify how you want to deal with cases where you have similarities between different points.

I leave this for you. Worst case scenario, you would eliminate the "most similar" points and then re-run the calculation.